# Data frame calculated column not calculating correctly

Tags: r, dataframe

```
deltas = 10^c(-1:-12)
df = data.frame(deltas)
df <- mutate(df, Num_H11 = -(
  Gamma_log_like(optout_gamma$par - c(df$deltas, 0), X)
  - 2 * Gamma_log_like(optout_gamma$par, X)
  + Gamma_log_like(optout_gamma$par + c(df$deltas, 0), X)) / (df$deltas^2)
  )
```

In the above code, if I replace `df$deltas` with a single delta value it all calculates correctly, but when i use a reference to a data frame column, the results are incorrect and I get the following warning:

```
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object lengthlonger object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I think the issue here is that df$deltas is being treated like a vector in this code, instead of just a single value from each row used and evaluated, but I am not sure how to fixx this.

Comment: Can you make this post reproducible and show the expected output for the same? What is `Gamma_log_like` or `optout_gamma` ?

Comment: `optout_gamma` is just a vector of two numbers. 
`gamma_log_like` is just a gamma log likelihood function that takes two params.
It's part of stats homework so I am reluctant to post entire code. This problem I am facing here is just an R problem, so i feel it's acceptable to ask.

Comment: I suspect that you just want `deltas` instead of `df$deltas`. You are correct in your assumption. Passing `df$deltas` passes the entire column into the function as if it were a vector. Please do your best to make your problems reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

From the description of the problem it seems that `Gamma_log_like` function is not vectorized. We can use `map_dbl` to pass input to `Gamma_log_like` function one at a time.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Num_H11 = purrr::map_dbl(deltas, ~
              -(Gamma_log_like(optout_gamma$par - c(.x, 0), X)
              - 2 * Gamma_log_like(optout_gamma$par, X)
              + Gamma_log_like(optout_gamma$par + c(.x, 0), X)) / (.x^2)
))
```